# Inserting data returned in another java file to a Derby DB in the current java file (same package/project)

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I have two .java files under the same package in a project folder in NetBeans IDE.

I am trying to use the following method to insert data to a Derby DB using JDBC:

```
public static void insertDisease(int id, String diseaseName, String diseaseDefinition) {
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("insert into " + tableName + " values (" + id + ",'" + diseaseName + "','" + diseaseDefinition + "')");
        stmt.close();
    } catch(SQLException sqlExcept) {
        sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have returned the data I need using the following method in another .java file (In the same package):

```
public List<String> nameOf() {
    String nameStr = null;
    List<String> nameResults = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int j=101;j<=110;j++) {
        refNum = j;

        try {                
            //crawl and parse HTML from definition and causes page
            Document docN = Jsoup.connect("http://www.abcde.edu/encylopedia/article/000" + refNum + ".htm").get();

            // scrape name data
            Elements name = docN.select("title");

            nameStr = name.get(0).text();
            //System.out.println(nameStr);

            nameResults.add(nameStr);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            nameStr = "No data";
            nameResults.add(nameStr);
            //System.out.println("Reference number " + refNum + " does not exist.");
        }            
    }
    return nameResults;
}
```

How should I implement my main method? This is what I have now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {
    createConnection();
    for(int i=101;i<=110;i++) {
        insertDisease(i, ?, ?);
    }
    viewTable(conn, dbURL);
}
```

What should go in as the 2nd and 3rd parameters (question marks) so that the names of the diseases from 101th to the 110th are inserted into my Derby DB correspondingly?

For Example, the table should look like the following:

```
id      name           definition
101     stomachache    stomach hurts
102     headache       head hurts
103     toothache      tooth hurts
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't know what to pass to your query? Also, learn a few things about [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)s.

Comment: @asgs, I know that I need to pass the name and the definition as parameters but can't figure out how to do it because they are in separate .java files. I can do it by writing it out as "stomachache" and "stomach hurts" but I want a loop to do it because I will be doing this 1000+ times.

Comment: A quicker way would be for the other Java file to return a `Map<String, List<String, String>>` where the key is the id of the insert query and the value is a `List` holding the disease name and description.